# Data node not starting..here is the log file

Tags: hadoop

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/hadoopuser/hdfs/datanode does not exist
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:747)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:524)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:409)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:156)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode$DataNodeDiskChecker.checkDir(DataNode.java:2239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2281)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2263)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2402)
2015-06-03 03:36:22,656 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.io.IOException: All directories in dfs.datanode.data.dir are invalid: "/hadoopuser/hdfs/datanode"
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2263)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2402)
2015-06-03 03:36:22,659 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2015-06-03 03:36:22,674 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at ubuntu/127.0.1.1
************************************************************
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you check the error log, and the property it is referring to before posting the question here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**STEP 1:** Create a new directory for datanode. Change ownership and permission.

```
su - hadoop
```

Enter password for hadoop user.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/hdfs/datanode
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/hdfs/datanode
sudo chown -R hadoop:hadoop /usr/local/hdfs/datanode
```

**STEP 2:** Change the value for `dfs.datanode.data.dir` in `hdfs-site.xml` as:

Change this

```
/hadoopuser/hdfs/datanode
```

to

```
/usr/local/hdfs/datanode
```

Now, restart your hadoop processes.

> **NOTE:** In "**su - hadoop**", **hadoop** is my hadoop username. If hadoop is not your username, change it to your username which you are
>   using to start and stop hadoop processes.

Comment: I solved the problem by creatind directory again ..thanks to all for answering.

Comment: sir can u plz tell me- i'm not able to start job and task tracker and their respective log files are also not made.

Answer (score 0):

Your jobtracker and tasktracker are all not start, how can you get the their log files.